# how to convert the html tags and get a message in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, email

how to convert the html tags to the msg bodg in mail function.

i.e i have

**Company Name:** BPL

**Industry Type:**

i have got the string as

datatable dt=new datatable();

string msg= dt.rows[i]["Message"].tostring();

i need to convert this html tags to the exact message;

```
           if (boolcheck)
            {
                msg.Body = ????????? wat to use over here.... how to remove the html tags and get the exact message

            }
```

pls help??????????/

Comment: Please be more specific. Show us a sample msg and how exactly should it look like in msg.Body

Comment: <p>Company name:</p>


i need to remove this <p> tags i.e html tags and show only the messages like compnayname ..  in that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you.

```
public string Strip(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @”<(.|\n)*?>”, string.Empty);
}
```

to remove a perticular tag try this one http://urenjoy.blogspot.com/2008/10/remove-html-tags-from-string.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular expressions

```
Regex.Replace(msg, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```